# Kendo Autocomplete doesn't bind model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I try to bind a object in the Kendo Autocomplete widget.
the trouble is that the model turns in a string when i fill the options, and when i change the scope the input show me the text [object object] because the model  isn't a string. is a object Example:

```
 Cliente : {NombreMostrar:''}
```

How i can link properly the model in way when i change the scope model, show me the name in the input, and when a selected a item from widget update correctly the object model.

```
 <input kendo-auto-complete k-ng-model="Credito.Cliente" k-options="ClientesBusqueda" style="width: 100%;" />

 $scope.ClientesBusqueda = {
    dataTextField: 'NombreMostrar',
    dataSource: {
        type: "get",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Cliente/Buscar",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                var newParams = {
                    clienteNombre: data.filter.filters[0].value
                };
                return newParams;
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (response) {
                var clientes = response.clientes.map(function (cliente) {
                    cliente.NombreMostrar = (cliente.RazonSocial || [cliente.ApellidoPaterno, cliente.ApellidoMaterno, cliente.PrimerNombre, cliente.SegundoNombre].join(' ')).toUpperCase();
                    cliente.RFC = cliente.RFC.toUpperCase();
                    return cliente;
                });
                return clientes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself i found a solution in this link, him create a directive for bind model to the control.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/custom-angular-directive-for-data-binding-on-teleriks-kendo-ui